# Oracle SQL generate query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

Following is my table schema.

Channel listing table:

```
    CHAN_NUMBER  CHAN_NAME   CHAN_TYPE
 ----------- -----------------------------------
      1 MTV                   Music
      2 ESPN                  Sports
      3 TNT                   Movies
      4 Fox                   Movies
      5 Fox                   Sports
```

customer survey table:

```
   SURV_ID SURV_DATE SURV_FAV_CHAN CUST_NUMBER
 ---------- --------- ------------- -----------
     1     25-NOV-12             1           2
     2     24-NOV-12             2           1
     3     24-NOV-12             3           3
     4     24-NOV-12             4           4
     5     24-NOV-12             5           5
     6     24-NOV-12             1           6
     7     24-NOV-12             2           7
     8     24-NOV-12             3           8
     9     24-NOV-12             4           9
    10     24-NOV-12             5          10
    11     24-NOV-12             1          11
```

I have these two tables that I need to generate a report that lists every `channel` and a `count of` how many `customers` have `selected that channel` as their `favorite`.

On oracle database I got up to the point where I am generating a count of each time a channel was selected as a favorite from the SURVEY table. But I can't **figure out how to join them** to create a list of channels displaying the `channel number`, the `name` and the `count of customers` who chose it as their favorite.

```
-- my channel table query


SELECT CHAN_NUMBER, CHAN_NAME FROM CHANNEL;


-- here is how I'm generating the couNt


SELECT COUNT(SURV_FAV_CHAN) FROM SURVEY
GROUP BY SURV_FAV_CHAN HAVING COUNT(SURV_FAV_CHAN) > 1;
```

ANY HELP WOULD BE AWESOME.

Comment: It would be great if you could update your question with the expected results :) Please take a look at the sample based answer I have put for you. Once you try it, do comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(CH.CHAN_NUMBER), MAX(CH.CHAN_NAME), COUNT(SRV.SURV_FAV_CHAN) FROM SURVEY SRV  
LEFT JOIN CHANNEL CH ON CH.CHAN_NUMBER = SRV.SURV_FAV_CHAN
GROUP BY SRV.SURV_FAV_CHAN HAVING COUNT(SRV.SURV_FAV_CHAN) > 1;
```

And you may want to use SUM(SRV.SURV_FAV_CHAN) if you really need the total amount of customers if I understand you question correctly

Comment: thanks Skegg99 this is exactly what I needed. My hat off to you.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this reference * [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f779/4)

You said you want **list every channel, and count of how many customers have selected that channel as their favourite**.

Let's go from nested to outside. Nested query you count number of customers from `Survery` table grouping by `favourite channel`. Every channel means, you need to do a `LEFT JOIN` on `Channels` table to get all the records.

Query:

```
(select c.*, s.ct from 
channel c
left join
(select count(cust_number) as ct
 , surv_fav_chan from survey
group by surv_fav_chan) as s
on c.chan_number = s.surv_fav_chan
;
```

Results:

```
CHAN_NUMBER     CHAN_NAME   CHAN_TYPE   CT
1               MTV         Music       3
2               ESPN        Sports      2
3               TNT         Movies      2
4               Fox         Movies      2
5               Fox         Sports      2
```

You seem to treat `FOX` as two channels offering two different types of programmes. So I have left it as it is. If you want to even count customers by channel type then please clarify.

PS: You may ignore the other old table schema in that SQLFIDDLE table sample. **NOTE** that it is in MYSQL, however this is an **ANSI** query - so you may apply it to ORACLE as well.

Comment: I get an error that I'm missing a keyword on line 6, with the AS keyword. Thanks for the help. Not sure if it's an Oracle thing.

Comment: @JoseCarrillo Yes as mentioned it's an oracle thing. So you may remove `AS` keyword. And please mark every answer that gives you a correct input. So the community would know that there are more than one solution for a question like yours. ;)

Comment: Here are further different variations of queries for you to play around :) [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/065e31/3)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `SURV_FAV_CHAN` and `CHAN_NUMBER` is the relation, use that for your `JOIN`, so try this:

```
SELECT CHAN_NUMBER
     , CHAN_NAME
     , COUNT(DISTINCT SURVEY.CUST_NUMBER) AS FAV_CHANNEL_CNT
FROM   CHANNEL
LEFT JOIN SURVEY
ON     SURVEY.SURV_FAV_CHAN = CHANNEL.CHAN_NUMBER
GROUP BY CHAN_NUMBER, CHAN_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks Bob this is a format I can understand a lot better and also provides me with the needed answer.